# What does it mean 'Be a hell of a way to go'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I watched tv shows for studying, found a line that i couldn't understand.
'Be a hell of a way to go.'
What does it mean??

Comment: It could mean several things, depending on the context. For example, you might say it about somebody who died in a particularly unpleasant way. It might refer to something that's a long way away. You can easily find explanations if idioms like this on the web, for example: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+hell+of+a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to say without more context, and it would help a lot if you could include something about the the lines before that line.  However, I can make a decent guess.

---

Firstly, it's probably a shortening of "**It** (or **that**) **would** be a hell of a way to go."  This kind of subject-dropping at the beginning of a sentence sometimes happens in informal speech where the subject is clear from context.  For example,

> "How's your dad?"
>   "Been sick." (where the full sentence would be "*He has* been sick")

This is sometimes called the *[null subject](http://artsites.uottawa.ca/clo-opl/doc/Null-Subject-in-English-Wonder-if-it-exists.pdf)*, or "[diary drop](http://www.academia.edu/3312460/The_relevance_of_referring_expressions_the_case_of_diary_drop_in_English)", because people often write that way in diaries.

---

[**A hell of a X** or **one hell of a** is an informal intensifier.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hell-of-a)  The exact meaning depends on context, but it always means something like "an especially noteworthy X".  It can be used with nouns or adjectives.  For example, you might say,

> He's a hell of a drinker.  (that is, *he's noteworthy for his drinking, probably for the amount of his drinking*)
>
> It made a hell of a big noise.  (that is, *it made an especially big noise*.)

---

[**Go** is one of those words in English that has many definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go), and you sometimes have to guess the correct one from context.  In this context, it probably means something like "to finish" or "to die".

---

So when we put all of that together, we get something like:

**That would be an especially noteworthy way to die.** or
**That would be an especially exciting way to finish something.**

You can see almost exactly this same phrase used here: [If last week was James Harrison's last game, it was a hell of a way to go out](http://www.sbnation.com/nfl/2016/1/20/10794710/steelers-james-harrison-pass-rusher-legend-hoss), where the author is saying, "If that was football player James Harrison's last game, it was a very noteworthy way to finish his career."

Comment: Note that "especially noteworthy" could mean very good *or* very bad. Can't really tell out of context.

Answer (score 0):

In general the phrase "A hell of a..." indicates something extreme and the phrase you've quoted means "a dramatic/exciting way to die".